# Change 64bit Registry from 32bit Python

Tags: python, window, registry, 32bit-64bit

I am having difficulty do understand this. If I'm correct, A 32bit Python can't run a code and change registry values in 64bit. Do I get it right? Or is there a switch to turn on in which enables this functionality?

There is this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

But how do I use it with the following code?
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/20/pythons-_winreg-editing-the-windows-registry/

Thanks, 
Oz

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the MSDN article you linked to explains, 64bit Windows has two registry *views*, one for 32bit and one for 64bit. By default a 32bit application (e.g. your Python script being executed by a 32bit Python interpreter) will access the 32bit view. You can force it to access the 64bit view using the flags mentioned in the MSDN article. To be able to use these flags you need to call `_winreg.OpenKey`, `_winreg.CreateKeyEx` or `_winreg.DeleteKeyEx` with the correct parameters, e.g.

```
handle = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "your_sub_key", 0, _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
```

See the [`_winreg` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) for more information.

Comment: if I do this: _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY i get an error: 'module'object has  no attribute 'KEY_WOW64_WOW'

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I can find `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` in the [_winreg 2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) but not in the [_winreg 2.6 docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.2/library/_winreg.html). Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Try using the constants' values directly: It is `0x0100` for `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` and `0x0200` for `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The Python 2.4 version of the `_winreg` module should support passing the flag to the `OpenKey` function. The relevant [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/lib/module--winreg.html) do not explicitely mention `CreateKeyEx` and `DeleteKeyEx` functions (which you need for passing the flags), but the former is mentioned at the bottom of the page so maybe they exist but are undocumented.