# Trying to get MachineGuid through _winreg but not working

Tags: python, windows, winreg

I can see the value in my registry editor and the path is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography`, but can't get the value with the following codes:

```
import _winreg

key = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography"
    )

result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "MachineGuid")

print result
```

I got **"The system cannot find the file specified"**, which is confusing because it's right there.

Well, there's no problem retrieving other values with the almost exact same code:

```
key = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\COM3"
    )


result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "BuildType")

print result
```

The output is: `(u'Free', 1)`

Which part am I doing wrong? What can I do to get this `MachineGuid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is working fine on a 32bit Windows, 
if you want it to also run on a 64bit Windows, try this :

```
key = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography",
    0,
    _winreg.KEY_READ | _winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY
)

result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "MachineGuid")
print result
```

Reference : [Change 64bit Registry from 32bit Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506646/change-64bit-registry-from-32bit-python)